# Bytes swapped using fread from binary (hex) file

Tags: c, binary, hex, endianness, fread

I have binary file (hex represented) with the following input,

```
0000 1900
```

and I am using the following code to read data into an integer.

```
 fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Error - Failed opening the file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else{
        printf("Disk image file [%s] opened...\n\n", argv[1]);
    }

int x = 0;
fread(&x, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
printf("Block count Hex: %x\n", x);
printf("Block count dec: %d\n", x);
```

Following output is produced, the bytes position seem to be swapped by the fread function.

```
Block count Hex: 190000
Block count dec: 1638400
```

If I have read around the endianness problem but this doesnt seem to match the output that I am getting. Any help to figure this out would be greatly appreciated.

Additional question:

-What is the best way to read the hex value stored in an int variable? I have been using %x with pŕintf and I am wondering if there is a better way to debug my code.

Comment: This does look like an endianess problem, maybe it would be more clear if you printed the hex number with left padded zeros which would be 00190000.  This is the exact reverse of what is in the file.  (This is assuming that the file contents that you gave us is in hex)

Comment: That's expected when you use little-endian `int`.

Comment: @user202729 Would the output not be 00 19 00 00 if it was little endian reversed?

Comment: ... You know that leading zeroes don't have any value, right?

Comment: Is the file produced by some other program writing a 4-byte integer? Or does it write two 2-byte integers? The functions `htonl` and `ntohl` may be useful.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson The file was indeed produced by other program with 4-byte integers, `htonl` and `ntohl` fixed the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To handle the problem of endianness when transferring data between computers or between applications, the functions `htonl` and `ntohl` are useful.